# How to tell to Javascript to compare the first element with the second and the second with the third and so on

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hello guys I am trying to solve this problem with Javascript.

I want to "automate" my code for each element of my array. I am trying to figure out how I can loop into that array and make a comparison between element n1 with the element n2 and so on., this is my kind of pseudo-code:

> is animal at position 0 === "sheep"? if not return 'Hey wolf go
> away!!' but  if yes i want to start another comparison, is the animal
> to position 1 === to animal at position 0?
>
> ```
> if yes return ' Hey sheep n0: Hello how are you?'
> if not return 'Hey sheep n0:  you are going to be eaten!;
> is the animal to position 1  === to animal at position 2? 
> if yes 'sheep n1: hello how are you?'
> if not return 'sheep n1 you are going to be eaten!'
> and so on
> ```

I  put in place my pseudo-code like this:

```
 function warnTheSheep(animal) {
  if (animal[0] === "wolf") {
    return "hey wolf go away!";
  } else if (animal[0] === "sheep" && animal[1] === "wolf") {
    return `hey sheep n(i) you are going to be eaten!! run`;
  } else {
    return "hey sheep n(i) hello how are you?";
  }
}

console.log(warnTheSheep(["sheep", "wolf", "wolf", "sheep"]));
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Can you clarify what's not working? Are you getting unexpected output? Crashing? More details would help

Comment: I want to "automate" my code to all the elements of the array I provided, instead with this I am comparing only the animal[0] with the animal[1] hardcoding basically everything.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what problems do you have with that approach? A loop would be a good start... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What should the function return then? You want the function to return a single string, but you now also want to compare `n` values and return a string for each? Need more clarity on the expected outputs still.

Comment: I think it will be better if you describe how the warning system works instead of using pseudocode. Describe it in terms of scenarios: What happens to  _animal[i]_ if _animal[i+1]_ is a wolf? What happens to _animal[i+1]_ if _animal[i]_ is a wolf?, Repeat the same scenarios, but with sheep instead of wolf. Also is the warning supposed to cascade or end after the first warning is issued?

Comment: I will delete this post and make another one clear with all my forEach loops and explain better what should return. sorry

Comment: Just update the question, no need to delete. Deleting questions with negative score can lead to a question ban, not the ideal way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for the patience guys I have just figured out the problem!, next time I'll make sure to open a clear topic, sorry again.
Thank you very much for your support, you are a fantastic community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gathered from your question, a very simple recursive approach could look something like this:

```js
function warnTheSheep(animal, index = 0) {
    if (index >= animal.length) {
        return;
    }

    if (animal[index] === "wolf") {
        console.log(`hey wolf n(${index}) go away!`);
    } else if (animal[index] === "sheep" && animal[index + 1] === "wolf") {
        console.log(`hey sheep n(${index}) you are going to be eaten!! run`);
    } else {
        console.log(`hey sheep n(${index}) hello how are you?`);
    }

    warnTheSheep(animal, index + 1);
}

warnTheSheep(["sheep", "wolf", "wolf", "sheep"]);
```

Your question was very unclear and some clarification would be appreciated in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about generating a useful array of warning messages.

The `getWarnings` function generates an array of statuses for each slot in the animals array. The `warnTheSheep` function just converts that to another array of nice human-readable messages.

```js
const Status = {
  Danger: 0,
  Safe: 1,
  Wolf: 2
}

const Animal = {
  Wolf: "wolf",
  Sheep: "sheep"
}

function getWarnings(animals) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    const animal = animals[i];
    const nextAnimal = animals[i + 1];
    if (animal === Animal.Wolf)
      result.push(Status.Wolf);
    else if (animal === Animal.Sheep && nextAnimal === Animal.Wolf)
      result.push(Status.Danger);
    else
      result.push(Status.Safe);
  }
  return result;
}

function warnTheSheep(animals) {
  const result = [];
  const warnings = getWarnings(animals);
  for (let i = 0; i < warnings.length; i++) {
    const warning = warnings[i];
    if (warning === Status.Safe)
      result.push(`hey sheep ${i} hello how are you?`);
    else if (warning === Status.Danger)
      result.push(`hey sheep ${i} you are going to be eaten!! run`);
    else
      result.push(`hey wolf go away`);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(warnTheSheep(["sheep", "wolf", "wolf", "sheep"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a matrix of threats for a given list of animals.
You can then filter the threat for the animal.

Note: this does not handle threats for animals with none like passing in `["goat"]` but I will leave that to you to work out.

```js
var animals = ["sheep", "wolf", "wolf", "sheep", "sheep"];
var animalthreats = [{
    name: "wolf",
    actions: [{
        targ: "sheep",
        do: "eat yummy"
      },
      {
        targ: "wolf",
        do: "say bye"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "sheep",
    actions: [{
        targ: "sheep",
        do: "Hi friend"
      },
      {
        targ: "wolf",
        do: "run from"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function warnTheSheep(beasts) {
  let x = "";
  beasts.forEach(function(beast, beastIndex) {
    x = beast;
    console.log("\n--------------------\nBeast:", x, beastIndex, "\n--------------------\n");
    let t = beasts[beastIndex + 1];
    if (typeof t == "undefined") return;
    let act = animalthreats.filter(threat => threat.name == t)[0];
    if(typeof act =="undefined") return;
    var dothis = act.actions.filter(a => a.targ == x)[0];
    console.log("I am", t, "I", dothis.do, x);
  });
  return "Done! no threat in line for " + x;
}

console.log(warnTheSheep(animals));
console.log(warnTheSheep(["sheep"]));
console.log(warnTheSheep(["pig","goat"]));
```

Answer (score -2):

if you wanted to automate it and compare your array with any index value you have to generate a random no.(int random_int = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min)) and then pass the value into the function.now use this value as index no.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).